# Update Session during ajax request then access Session in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, kendo-grid, asp.net-ajax

Session["SelectedRecords"] is used to contain the Id's of selected records, e.g.

```
SelectedRecords: 1108392 1108393 1108394
```

When I fire an ajax post that removes an id from the Session["SelectedRecords"] which as far as server side is concerned successfully removes the ID from Session["SelectedRecords"]...

```
List<int> ids = SessionHelper.GetSelectedRecordIds();

ids.Remove(selectedItemModel.Id);

string csv = string.Join<int>(",", ids);

this.Session["SelectedRecords"] = csv;
```

using an onSuccess/onRequestEnd event I then use console.log to output the Session["SelectedRecords"] to check.

```
function onRequestEnd(e) {
    console.log('onRequestEnd SelectedRecords: ' + @Session["SelectedRecords"]);
}
```

But the console.log shows that Session["SelectedRecords"] (as far as the client is concerned still contains the removed id?!)

So the question is when I remove a value from Session["SelectedRecords"] via an ajax post and afterwards access Session["SelectedRecords"] in the view, the view is reporting 'old' values i.e. not the latest values?!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you have one object in Session and you POST a delete, you have to remove it also from the Session. This is done like below:

```
Session.Remove("key");
```

where key is the unique key you have used to store the item in the `Session`.

**However**, in your case this will not work. You have to do two things:

- Remove the SelectedRecords from the Session.
- Add the new SelectedRecords (without the one record you deleted with your POST) to the Session.

After doing this (which after your update it seems you already have this logic in your code), you have to return back to the client the new SelectedRecords and replace the old value with the new.

Something like this:

```
$("#selectedRecords").val(newSelectedRecords)
```

The above should be executed in the success callback of your AJAX call.

Comment: Indeed, I am removing it from the Session (on server side ajax post) and am then adding them to Session as per my above code edit.

Comment: Sorry for the 'bitty' updates... see now... I am doing this using onRequestEnd, and have previously tried OnDataBound... see the OnRequestEnd function I've just added.